# How can I remove the .html from the URL?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I am creating a page using only JavaScript and the page that I am being redirected from the main html file has a .html extension.(`http://127.0.0.1:5501/products.html`)  . I want my URL file to be `http://127.0.0.1:5501/products`. I also need to mention that I am not using a server at the moment and I am fetching the products from a JSON local file using async and await. How to remove the .html in the URL?

The link redirection in my index.html file :

```
 <li><a href="./products.html">Продукти</a></li>
```

and my JavaScript file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
spinner.style.display = 'block';
const fetchHoney = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/products.json');
        const data = await response.json();
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status:${response.status}`)
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        content.innerHTML = "There was a problem! Please refresh the page and try again.";
        content.classList.add('errorMsg');
    }

}

fetchHoney().then(data => {
    let arrayPrice = '';
content.style.display = 'none';



    const displayHoney = () =>{
        const filteredHoney = data.filter(data => data.listing === 'honey');
        const productsHoney = filteredHoney.map((product) => {
            const {id,name,image,price} = product;

            if (Array.isArray(price)) {
                arrayPrice = price.join(' денари - ');;
            } else {
                arrayPrice = price;
            }

            return `    
            <div class="b-products__wrap">
            <div class="bla">
            <img class="b-products__img b-products__img${id}" src="${image}" alt="">
            
            </div>
            <div class="b-products__name b-products__name${id}">${name}</div>
            <div class="b-products__price">${arrayPrice} денари</div>       
            </div>`;
        }).join('');

    honeyProducts.innerHTML = productsHoney;

    }


  const displayBees = () =>{
      const filteredBees = data.filter(data => data.listing === 'bee');
        const productsBees = filteredBees.map((product) => {

            const {id,name,image,price} = product;


            if (Array.isArray(price)) {
                arrayPrice = price.join(' денари - ');
                console.log(arrayPrice);
            } else {
                arrayPrice = price;
            }

            return `
            <div class="b-products__wrap">
            <div class="bla">
            <img class="b-products__img b-products__img${id}" src="${image}" alt="">
            
            </div>
            <div class="b-products__name b-products__name${id}">${name}</div>
            <div class="b-products__price">${arrayPrice} денари</div>
            </div>`;
        }).join('');
        
        beeProducts.innerHTML = productsBees;

  }  
  displayHoney();
  displayBees();

  setTimeout(() => {
spinner.style.display = 'none';      
content.style.display = 'flex';

 }, 1000);

  });

})
```

Comment: What happens if you change it to `<a href="./products">`?

Comment: I am receiving an error (Cannot GET /products in the browser and  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in the console)

Comment: How do you serve the files? Nginx? Apache?

Comment: Currently I am only using a local development environment i.e XAMPP, because the page is in production.

Comment: you can have a "products" directory inside your website with an index.php on it

Comment: You clearly *are* using a server, because you've got `http://` URLs. Even if it's on your local machine, the software that responds to those requests is a "server".